# Prestashop 1.7 overriding .tpl files using module

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am trying to create a module in prestashop 1.7.* . I have got into a situation which needs me to edit **cart.tpl** file located in **themes/classic/templates/checkout** folder. In documentation I came across */themes/[theme_name]/modules* which has the description as "*Sub-folder for overriding .tpl files and languages files, if necessary.*" . Unable to find proper explanation I tried creating **"MyModule/themes/classic/templates/checkout/cart.tpl"** and unfortunately the changes are not reflected in the site. I have no clue what should be done.

P.S When I tried creating a hook and placing it by altering the **themes/classic/templates/checkout/cart.tpl** file it was successful. I am planning to place my hook in my module's overriding *cart.tpl* file.

Comment: Which hook you have tried? I also want to change the cart.tpl Please let me know which changes you have done for this issue? @curious_coder

Comment: @Shefali: As there were no answers, I don't remember the solution which I tried.